# Astra theme disabling javascript links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a working calendar demo. I have tested the code on more than one theme and everything works perfectly. The code however won't work with Astra Theme which is what I am using for my WordPress Website. I am not sure what the problem is at this point maybe someone would help me with this. This code also adds links to the dates. The problem is that Astra Theme strips the dates of the links when you change the date using the navigation buttons or date/month selector. Other themes seem to work perfectly. I checked console for errors and this is what I see:

```
(index):267 Uncaught TypeError: links is not a function
    at previous ((index):267)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):182)
```

The code is

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-calendar">
      <h3 id="monthAndYear"></h3>
      <div class="button-container-calendar">
        <button id="previous" onclick="previous()">&#8249;</button>
        <button id="next" onclick="next()">&#8250;</button>
      </div>

      <table class="table-calendar" id="calendar" data-lang="en">
        <thead id="thead-month"></thead>
        <tbody id="calendar-body"></tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="footer-container-calendar">
        <label for="month">Jump To: </label>
        <select id="month" onchange="jump()">
          <option value=0>Jan</option>
          <option value=1>Feb</option>
          <option value=2>Mar</option>
          <option value=3>Apr</option>
          <option value=4>May</option>
          <option value=5>Jun</option>
          <option value=6>Jul</option>
          <option value=7>Aug</option>
          <option value=8>Sep</option>
          <option value=9>Oct</option>
          <option value=10>Nov</option>
          <option value=11>Dec</option>
        </select>
        <select id="year" onchange="jump()"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


 <script>
function generate_year_range(start, end) {
  var years = "";
  for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
    years += "<option value='" + year + "'>" + year + "</option>";
  }
  return years;
}

var today = new Date();
var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
var selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
var selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");


var createYear = generate_year_range(2016, 2021);
/** or
 * createYear = generate_year_range( 1970, currentYear );
 */

document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = createYear;

var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
var lang = calendar.getAttribute('data-lang');

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

var dayHeader = "<tr>";
for (day in days) {
  dayHeader += "<th data-days='" + days[day] + "'>" + days[day] + "</th>";
}
dayHeader += "</tr>";

document.getElementById("thead-month").innerHTML = dayHeader;


monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);



function next() {
  currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
  currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
  showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
  links () 
}

function previous() {
  currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
  currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
  showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
  links () 
}

function jump() {
  currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
  currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
  showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
  links () 
}

function showCalendar(month, year) {

  var firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();

  tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body");


  tbl.innerHTML = "";


  monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
  selectYear.value = year;
  selectMonth.value = month;

  // creating all cells
  var date = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cellText = document.createTextNode("");
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      } else if (date > daysInMonth(month, year)) {
        break;
      } else {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.setAttribute("data-date", date);
        cell.setAttribute("data-month", month + 1);
        cell.setAttribute("data-year", year);
        cell.setAttribute("data-month_name", months[month]);
        cell.className = "date-picker";
        cell.innerHTML = "<span>" + date + "</span>";

        if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
          cell.className = "date-picker selected";
        }
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      }


    }

    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }

}

function daysInMonth(iMonth, iYear) {
  return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate();
}

function links () {
document.querySelectorAll('td.date-picker > span').forEach(element => {
  var year = element.parentElement.getAttribute('data-year');
  var month = element.parentElement.getAttribute('data-month');
  var day =  element.textContent;
  if (month.length === 1) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }
    if (day.length === 1) {
    day = "0" + day;
  }
  element.innerHTML = '<a href="https://example.com/dates/' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day + '">' + element.textContent + '</a> '
})
}

links ()
</script>
```

Comment: this sounds llike you forgot to add the function **function links () {....** in another page when you click on a day....

Comment: This sounds like a question for the Astra theme support. If it works on other themes, then their code must be doing something different and they are the ones best placed to know what it is.

Comment: I don't think this is really about adding the code in another page because this whole block of code is working well in other themes. @FluffyKitten I understand. I posted the question on their support forum but it has not been replied to. I am trying to be patient though time is really not on my side. Thanks for the reminder though.